# Alternate div to have images left(even) or right(odd)

Tags: html, css

I am trying have a better arrangement of images instead of just images in 1 column. 
See example in attachment, the images for each article can be on left and right.

[image]

This is my code.
HTML:

```
<section class="content list_page">
    <article id="post-66">
        <div class="list_img"><img src="img1.png"></div>
        <div class="list_text">Content 1</div>
    </article>
    <article id="post-63">
        <div class="list_img"><img src="img2.png"></div>
        <div class="list_text">Content 2</div>
    </article>
    .
    .
    .
</section >
```

CSS:

```
.list_page:nth-child(odd) .list_img{ 
    float:right; 
}
.list_page:nth-child(even) .list_img{
     float:left;
}
```

How do I do that? Please help.
-Thanks in advance

Comment: Use css property display:inline-block; or display:inline;

Comment: Shouldn't `:nth-child()` be applied to `article` instead of `.list_page`?

Comment: @BillyNate Yes :\ , Shall I remove this question?

Comment: **Don't** use `inline-block` or `inline`, that's BS, your divs are `block` and applying `float` to a `block` is perfectly fine!

Comment: @Aasim - Just accept an answer. They are pretty much all the same, pick your best fit ;) I think Tharaka's explanation is the most complete.

Comment: As a bonus you might want to try to set `article > img { display:block }` and apply the float directly on the `img`. Saves you a wrapping element ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this css

```
.list_page article:nth-child(odd) .list_img{ 
    float:right; 
}
.list_page article:nth-child(even) .list_img{
     float:left;
}
```

Problem is you selecting the parent div not the child article

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work if you select the article

```
<style>

article:nth-child(odd) .list_img{ 
    float:right; 
}
article:nth-child(even) .list_img{
     float:left;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you use bad selector for odd and even. No ".list_page" but "article" tag

```
article:nth-child(odd) .list_img{ 
    float:right; 
}
article:nth-child(even) .list_img{
     float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mraranturnik/3u64jaew/